# Comparing two arrays in swift, with different lengths

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to compare two arrays with each other and append the value that is not in the other array to a new array. The problem now is that all of the values that does not equal the other array already get appended, but I want only the values that are new in the other array getting appended.

I hope that the problem is clear. Sorry if it's a very vague question. I try to be clear haha.
The code and output is printed below:

```
// Iterate through all possible values
for i in 0...messages.count-1{
    var match = false

    for r in 0...self.messages.count-1{
       println("NIEUWE" + messages[i].getID() + "OUDE" + self.messages[r].getID())


        if(messages[i].getID().toInt() == self.messages[r].getID().toInt()){

            var match = true

            println(match)
            break
        }


    }

    if (!match) {
        newArray.append(messages[i])
        println(newArray)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
NIEUWE170OUDE170
NIEUWE170OUDE171
true
[PostDuif.Message]
NIEUWE171OUDE170
true
[PostDuif.Message, PostDuif.Message]
NIEUWE172OUDE170
true
```

Comment: The arrays are already in the same order, just one is missing some elements?  Or might they be in totally different orders?

Comment: Does the order of the array matter? If it doesn't, turn them both into Sets and you'll be able to union/intersect them.

Comment: The arrays are eventually not in order. One of the elements in the new array is added randomly, and need to be appended to the last index of the old array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "I want to compare two arrays with each other and append the value that is not in the other array to a new array" is just 'set difference'

```
var s1 = Set(["a", "b", "c"])   // this to be similar to your need
var s2 = Set(["b", "c", "d"])    
var s3 = s2.subtract (s1)
```

As such:

```
  9> var s3 = s2.subtract(s1)
s3: Set<String> = {
  [0] = "d"
}
```

Note that you have `subtract`, `intersect`, and `union` with `inPlace` options as methods on the `Set` type.  New to Swift 1.2.

Comment: OK, it worked! Thank you very much the help. Can now get further with my project :)

Comment: This does not work for as i have two arrays containing string and storing the result in third array which is also of the type string

Comment: This does't work for me "[String] does not have a member subtract"

Comment: `subtract` is a method on the `Set` type; not on the `Array` type. [Do I get down-voted even when I say `Set([...])`??]